# jscrollPane scrollbar doesn't appear on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jscrollPane to showcase a portfolio of images. When initially loaded, the slider disappears. After reloading, it appears.

You can replicate the effect by visiting [here](http://www.opohills.com/portfolio/donwa.php) 
(When you visit the first time, you see a group of three images, with no slider below it. When you reload it, you see that everything is loaded)

I think it might be because the images might take time to load, though I'm not sure what the cause could be.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Your are getting this issue on which browser??

Comment: On Chrome. I think it has to do with image loading after jScrollPane etc. Still not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with when I loaded jScrollpane. It's best practice anyways, but make sure to load jScrollepane at the end of you  tag, not your  tag